Python で __file__ の代わりに使うべきなのは何ですか？
Pythonで、main.py と同じフォルダにlogフォルダがあり、そのlogフォルダを相対パスで取得してログを吐き出したいのですが、os.path.dirname( __file__ ) はEXE化した際に生成環境によって値がかわってしまい、バグの温床となるというようなサイトを見ました。
__file__ はmain.pyの中で多用しており、EXE化後に実際ファイルが見つからないエラーが出ていますので、__file__ を修正したいのですが、相対パスを __file__ を使用しないで書く方法はありますでしょうか？

参照したのと同じ記事かもしれませんが、書かれている対策の方も参考になるのでは？ [Python exe化]実行ファイル化したPythonプログラムでは__file__を使わない方が良い。[path バグる原因]

何らかのプログラム実行形式は、通常ユーザーには書き込み権限が無い C:\Program Files\ほげ 以下にインストールされる（インストールする）流儀なので、ログファイルを EXE と同じディレクトリに書きだすという仕様自体を改めたほうが良いっス。絶対あとで困る（末端ユーザーが困るか作者であるあなたが困るかは別）

ちなみにPyInstallerだとドキュメントにはこんな風に書かれています。Using sys.executable and sys.argv[0]

UNIX/Linuxなら、XDG Baseに従う、Windowsなら環境変数LocalAppDataにアプリ用フォルダ作成ですかね

開発リテラシーも大事ですが、技術的に再現できる技能も大事だと思うので回答させてもらった内容を参考にしてもらえれば幸いです。

下記関数を呼び出して戻り値を見てください。
自作関数なのでマシな書き方があれば勝手に改善してもらって構いません。
原理としては、EXE化前か、EXE化後かを判別してEXEファイルのディレクトリを読み込む方法を2系統用意しています。
import os
import sys

def getExeFileDirectory():
    '''
        exeファイルが存在するディレクトリを取得する関数
    '''
    try:
        
        if getattr(sys, "frozen", False):
            # EXE化していればexecutableで取得
            script_dir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
        else:
            # EXE化していなければ__file__で取得
            script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        
        return script_dir
    except Exception as e:
        return None

